# Jinja2 escape the filter operator ("|")

Tags: python, jinja2

In jinja2, the operator `|` is used as filtering, such as  `{{ user_input | safe }}`. However, `|` is also a valid python operator, say bitwise-or, set union, etc. Suppose I have the following code in a template

```
{% for elem in (set1 | set2) %} elem.render_some_string() {% endfor %}
```

Jinja throws an exception

```
File "some_template_file.txt", line xxx, in template
    {% for elem in (set1 | set2) %} elem.render_some_string() {% endfor %}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'set2'
```

which is understandable. But is there a way around this, say tell jinja to not interpret the `|` operator as a filter? I'd hope to have a solution better than "replace `(set1 | set2)` with `set1.union(set2)`" --- unless that is the only possible solution (or only recommended solution).

Comment: To my knowledge, the suggested solution is the way to go. But happy to learn if there's a way to override things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `|` in Jinja2 expressions to operate anything else than a Jinja2 filter operation.
Every statement using `{%%}` or `{{}}` (and so on) is not really python. It is a Jinja langage, lexed, parsed by Jinja and executed. Every piece of code you put is not "evaled" as you might though but even the `+` is parsed and executed in the parser module of Jinja2 ([github-Jinja2/parser.py#L450](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/c97fa109d38b5367ce3efffb6e435d007dc55920/jinja2/parser.py#L450)). Thus the `|` is a token of the Jinja grammar and cannot be reversed to its python meaning.

The reason why you can call your methods is because your objects are still the real ones and they keep all their capabilies. The solution that you suggest to use `.union` is the only available solution you have.

FYI: There is no opened (or closed) issue in Jinja2 to allow such a possibility (and it might get refused if did one in my opinion)